# c# Save a file from third party to memory instead of disk

Tags: c#, .net

I have a third-party library (written in vc c++, source code not avilable). I have written a c# wrapper around this library.

One of the methods in this third-party sdk, accepts a file path and saves a stream of data into this file. Instead of saving the file to disk, I wonder if there is a way for me to control it so the file will be saved to a memory stream I can access?

Comment: Presumably you have access to this file before the SDK is called? So just read it? Of course don't forget you'll have to handle concurrent access, etc. yourself. You can't access a C++ memory stream (does C++ even have memory streams?) from C#

Comment: I don't have access to this file before SDK is called. The SDK creates the file.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: Then you can't access it. you can't access memory of a C++ dll. It essentially runs in a separate memory space .Net can utilise what it exposes. If it doesn't expose the memory stream (I'm not even sure this would be possible) then you have no way to access it.

Comment: Hm, have you looked in the library with ilspy or ildasm?

Comment: @Liam that is not entirely correct. you can use unsafe code, native Windows apis (`ReadProcessMemory` for example) to read it directly. not sure how low level you wish to go on this though.

Comment: I mean if the OP wants to try and read memory directly and try and turn this into something meaningful then good luck with that! But I take your point